# Clear HTML element from any css classes?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with class "class1" . And a class: .class1 input {etc}  so that all the inputs in the div get styled.

Is there away to make sure one specific input in the div does not get styled, but instead keeps the default input styling/button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either:

(1) Amend `.class1 input {etc}` to `.class1 input.a {etc}` and apply the style `a` to all your inputs bar the special one.

or

(2) apply an inline style to the special input in question resetting its format.

Comment: How would go about doing option 2? Never heard of an inline style to 'reset format'

Comment: @Jonah Katz: Option 2 is impossible.

Comment: @BoltClock Why do you say it's impossible? An inline style will override any styles that were set before it thus giving you the ability to "reset" the style.

Comment: @DDoSAttack: Sigh... I'll just repost my earlier comment here: override styles aren't an option. You can't use overrides to revert an input style to browser defaults.

Comment: Sigh... I never said it would automatically revert the input to its browser default. I said you can override any style with an inline style and "reset" (note the double quotes implying that it is not a "real" "true" reset) any styles set before it. Thus you could **manually** reset the style to what appears to be the browser default. Hence the **cascading** part of cascading style sheets ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no `:not` selector in CSS 2.1, your best bet would be to assign classes to all of the inputs that you want to have a certain style. Then, target them like this:

```
.class1 .inputclass1
```

and then your other input (the one that needs default styling) won't be affected.

If you want to use CSS 3, then you can use `:not` like so:

```
.class1:not(.defaultclass1)
```

and give `defaultclass1` to the element you want to have default styling.

Comment: You must not have heard about CSS3 yet: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation

Comment: again someone with the same kind of answer and 37 seconds faster at posting than me XD

Comment: @BoltClock yes, no one is arguing against that CSS3 has some awesome stuff, but it's not integrated in the market enough yet

Comment: @Joseph: A few seconds before my comment, the answer read "no :not selector in CSS", and I kinda jumped the gun.

Comment: @BoltClock Oh I see now. That's understandable.

Answer (score 0):

in a situation like that you have two kinds of inputs in this div.  one that should be styled and one that shouldn't.  You basically have two classes of inputs, but you haven't givven them class names. I would suggest giving them class names (e.g. styled and nonstyled or what not) and basing your css off of that.  Otherwise you could use a pseudoclass, but that I'm not too sure on.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the :not() selector. However, this is not supported by IE. Probably easiest to provide a CSS over-ride for the specific input that you would like to be "default" styled.

Answer (score 0):

in case you are planning to support all browser which do not support CSS3. You can over-ride the rule by making another class. like

```
    .class input {etc}
    and then over-ride etc rule by giving some other class to that input e.g. .notClass

    input.notClass {over-ride etc }
```

Comment: See my comment on Jesse's answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use .class imput[type]{} if this is another type of input
2. Best way is use a class for that all input like .class1 input.all{} and leave the non style one without any class